# Sharing internet to wlan0 AP from already bridged eth0

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, wireless-access-point

My purpose is simple. I want to share internet available on ethernet eth0 to wlan0 which is acting as an access point. But I have already made a bridge br-lan between eth0 and tap0. So I am not able bridge br0 with eth0 and wlan0. Here is my

/etc/network/interfaces

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
address 0.0.0.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
address 0.0.0.0

auto br-lan
iface br-lan inet dhcp
       bridge-ports eth0

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.2.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
        bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
        bridge_fd 1
        bridge_hello 1
        bridge_stp on
```

ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:7c:22:88:18  
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::217:7cff:fe22:8818/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4901 (4.9 KB)

br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:9f:04:10:39  
          inet addr:192.168.1.125  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd00:aaaa::204:9fff:fe04:1039/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fd45:6807:17db:0:204:9fff:fe04:1039/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fd00:aaaa::85c:ae5a:130d:40f/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::204:9fff:fe04:1039/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd45:6807:17db:0:85c:ae5a:130d:40f/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1039 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:393281 (393.2 KB)  TX bytes:23516 (23.5 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:9f:04:10:39  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1177 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:478095 (478.0 KB)  TX bytes:32178 (32.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6483 (6.4 KB)  TX bytes:6483 (6.4 KB)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7e:e0:12:05:00:39  
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ce0:12ff:fe05:39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:4385 (4.3 KB)  TX bytes:282726 (282.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:7c:22:88:18  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3724 (3.7 KB)
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# 802.11n related stuff
ieee80211n=1
noscan=1
ht_capab=[HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]

#WPA2 settings
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Most modern wireless drivers in the kernel need driver=nl80211
#driver=nl80211
driver=rtl871xdrv
max_num_sta=8
beacon_int=100
wme_enabled=1
wpa_group_rekey=86400
device_name=RTL8192CU
manufacturer=Realtek

# set proper interface
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
# best channels are 1 6 11 14 (scan networks first to find which slot is free)
channel=6
# this is the network name
ssid=***
wpa_passphrase=***
```

/etc/dnsmasq.d/dhcp.conf

```
dhcp-range=192.168.2.100,192.168.2.200,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.2.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.2.1
dhcp-authoritative
```

route

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br-lan
    192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
    192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

brctl show

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-lan      8000.00049f041039   no      eth0
                            tap0
br0     8000.00177c228818   yes     wlan0
```

ip route

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br-lan 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br-lan  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.125 
192.168.2.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

So I am able to access internet from the linux machine and host an AP through br0(wlan0) and get my mobile connected to it and obtain IP and ping 192.168.2.1 from my mobile.

As I see it eth0 cannot be bridged with br0 as it is already bridged with br-lan. So how can I can give internet to br0 or wlan0 (the wifi AP)??

I can ping both networks.

ping 192.168.1.1

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.856 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.816 ms
```

ping 192.168.2.149

```
PING 192.168.2.149 (192.168.2.149) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.149: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.149: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.58 ms
```